# PHP different 2 arrays and use conditions in comparison

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays follow this:

Array A

```
Array
(
       [0] => Array
            (
                [TD_CODE] => 24203
                [CRS_NAME] => Adobe Photoshop CS6+CC            
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [TD_CODE] => 24202
                [CRS_NAME] => Advance Microsoft excel 2010/2007
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [TD_CODE] => 24197
                [CRS_NAME] => Beginning Auditor Tools and Techniques

            )
    );
```

And Array B

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [crs_id] => 1
            [crs_ia_id] => 2017-6495
            [crs_oracle_id] => 24653
            [crs_name] => Windows8          
            [crs_start_date] => 2017-08-07
            [crs_end_date] => 2017-08-11

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [crs_id] => 2
            [crs_ia_id] => 2017-5013
            [crs_oracle_id] => 24202
            [crs_name] => Advance Microsoft excel 2010/2007
            [crs_start_date] => 2017-02-08
            [crs_end_date] => 2017-02-09

        )
```

)

I want to make array A different array B.
The condition is to use `TD_CODE` of the array A *compared* to `crs_oracle_id` of array b And and take it as array C.

So The results are as follows.

```
Array
(
       [0] => Array
            (
                [TD_CODE] => 24203
                [CRS_NAME] => Adobe Photoshop CS6+CC            
            )

      [1] => Array
            (
                [TD_CODE] => 24197
                [CRS_NAME] => Beginning Auditor Tools and Techniques

            )
    );
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get ids from second array which needs to be rejected, then add only those records which doesn't exists in this id array,

```
$rejected_ids = array_column($b,'crs_oracle_id');
$c = [];
foreach($a as $v){
    if(!in_array($v['TD_CODE'], $rejected_ids)){
        $c[] = $v;
    }
}

print_r($c);
```

***array_column*** — Return the values from a single column in the input array

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6cb77b92ce01feb0c974256534cc7c632af160e)

**EDIT**

Here is more optimized code,

```
$c = array_filter($a, function($v,$k) use($rejected_ids){
    return !in_array($v['TD_CODE'], $rejected_ids);
},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f025aa76d7201da0c518701cce9f42046b9fd76c).

***array_filter*** — Filters elements of an array using a callback function

***ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH*** - pass both value and key as arguments to **callback** instead of the value

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your answer is very helpful to me. I never knew the array_filter functions. Now I know how to use it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to help mate!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with anonymous function to compare `TD_CODE` and `crs_oracle_id`

```
$array_c = array_filter($array_a, function($e) use($array_b) {
    foreach ($array_b as $v) {
        if ($v['crs_oracle_id'] == $e['TD_CODE']) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

print_r($array_c);
```

Comment: @rahulsm: The condition states that if `crs_oracle_id` and `TD_CODE` is equal, return `false`. Which filters the element. Thus, not including it in the output. Please evaluate codes carefully. :)

Comment: Ohh sorry, My bad. Your code is correct. but you can write return true on not equal to also. return false and return true both are not neccessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Your answer helped me learn how to solve this problem. And have learned that little bug. Don't delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP Version is below 5.5 Then Please use this function

```
if (! function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column(array $input, $columnKey, $indexKey = null) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($input as $value) {
            if ( !array_key_exists($columnKey, $value)) {
                trigger_error("Key \"$columnKey\" does not exist in array");
                return false;
            }
            if (is_null($indexKey)) {
                $array[] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
            else {
                if ( !array_key_exists($indexKey, $value)) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not exist in array");
                    return false;
                }
                if ( ! is_scalar($value[$indexKey])) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not contain scalar value");
                    return false;
                }
                $array[$value[$indexKey]] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

ARRAY - A

```
$array_a = Array
(
       '0' => Array
            (
                'TD_CODE' => '24203',
                'CRS_NAME' => 'Adobe Photoshop CS6+CC'          
            ),

        '1' => Array
            (
                'TD_CODE' => '24202',
                'CRS_NAME' => 'Advance Microsoft excel 2010/2007'
            ),

        '2' => Array
            (
                'TD_CODE' => '24197',
                'CRS_NAME' => 'Beginning Auditor Tools and Techniques'

            )
    );
```

ARRAY - B

```
$array_b = Array
(
    '0' => Array
        (
            'crs_id' => '1',
            'crs_ia_id' => '2017-6495',
            'crs_oracle_id' => '24653',
            'crs_name' => 'Windows8',        
            'crs_start_date' => '2017-08-07',
            'crs_end_date' => '2017-08-11'

        ),

    '1' => Array
        (
            'crs_id' => '2',
            'crs_ia_id' => '2017-5013',
            'crs_oracle_id' => '24202',
            'crs_name' => 'Advance Microsoft excel 2010/2007',
            'crs_start_date' => '2017-02-08',
            'crs_end_date' => '2017-02-09'

        )
        );
```

ARRAY - C

```
$array_c = array();


        foreach ($array_a as $a){

        if(!in_array($a['TD_CODE'], array_column($array_b, 'crs_oracle_id'))) {
            $array_c[] = array('TD_CODE' => $a['TD_CODE'],'CRS_NAME'=>$a['CRS_NAME']);
        }
        }
        print_r($array_c);
```